# Using Partition to allow sublists of different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

As a minimal example, suppose I have a list of the integers from 1 to 25.  Suppose I want to use `Partition` to partition the list into sublists of length 10 **but** without dropping the "end" elements.

For example, this code

```
list = Range[1, 25];
Partition[list, 10]
```

gives: `{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}}`, where the integers 21 through 25 have been dropped.  What if I want to keep those integers?  I would like `Partition` to partition the list into sublists of length 10 only when possible (i.e., keeping the "end" elements).  How can I do this?

In the `Partition` documentation, this entry looks like a possibility:

> `Partition[list, n, d, {kL, kR}, {}]`
>   uses no padding, and so can yield sublists of different lengths.

So I tried:

Partition[list, 10, 0, {1, 1}, {}]

but this did not work (according to the documentation `{kL, kR} = {1, 1}` means "allow maximal overhang at the end").

On the other hand, this seems to work:

```
Partition[list, 10, 10, 1, {}]
```

which gives the correct output: `{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25}}`.

Is this the best way to solve the problem, or am I making a conceptual mistake?  I obtained the idea `Partition[list, 10, 10, 1, {}]` from the following documentation, but conceptually I am not really sure what it is doing:

> Use no padding, so later sublists can be shorter:
>   `Partition[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g},3,3,1,{}]`
>
> `{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g}}`

Comment: Related: [(28416)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28416/121),
[(128133)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128133/121)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct syntax:

```
Partition[list, 10, 10, 1, {}]
```

The fourth argument is a short form of `{1, 1}` so the full form is:

```
Partition[list, 10, 10, {1, 1}, {}]
```

As the documentation says:

> Partition[list, n, d, {k<sub>L</sub>, k<sub>R</sub>}]
>   specifies that the first element of list should appear at position k<sub>L</sub> in
>   the first sublist, and the last element of list should appear at or
>   after position k<sub>R</sub> in the last sublist. If additional
>   elements are needed, Partition fills them in by treating list as
>   cyclic.

You need the arguments `10, 10` because this means lengths of ten without overlap.  (Take 10, move over ten, take another ten...)

Answer (score 12):

Since Mathematica 10.3, we can use the much more convenient [`UpTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html):

```
Partition[Range[25], UpTo[10]]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
    {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}} *)
```

Comment: Does `UpTo` work in `Part`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, but it works in `Take`. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I was just curious.  I like to use `Part` a lot so I wondered if something like `foo[[ ;; UpTo[5] ]]` would work.  It may be best that it does not as that could add overhead to every `Part` call.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``:

```
r = Range[25];
qr[m_, n_] := 
 Module[{a = QuotientRemainder[m, n]}, 
  Table[n, {a[[1]]}]~Join~{a[[2]]}]
Internal`PartitionRagged[r, qr[25, 10]]
```

yields:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
   20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}}
```