# Reversibly merging sets of $k$ adjacent elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, list-manipulation

Say I have an array of the form:

```
ExampleArray = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}};
```

I'd like to be able to reversibly merge sets of $k$ adjacent elements together s.t. I can go back and forth from, for example, arrays of the form:

```
ExampleArray = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}};
```

And, for $k = 2$:

```
ExampleArray2Star = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13}};
```

Or, for $k = 3$:

```
ExampleArray3Star = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13}};
```

As we can see here, "leftover" elements at the end of the array will strictly be in a subset of size $\leq k$.

Is there a name for this sort of operation, and is there an easy way to execute it in Mathematica 9.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way, using [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html):

```
func[l_, n_] := Partition[l, n, n, {1, 1}, {}]
```

(the key is to use proper padding, see also in documentation of [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html))

example:

```
func[Range@13, #] & /@ Range[5]

{
  {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}},
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13}}, 
  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13}}, 
  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13}}, 
  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13}}
}
```

**Note**
For generality, I assumed that the input (`l` that is) is "flat". In your case, you want to `Flatten` it, e.g. `func[Flatten[ExampleArray], #] & /@ Range[5]`.

**Addendum**:

You might want to look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size), especially at the `dynP` function there - it discusses varying partition lengths.

Comment: +1, but note that the OP input is not `Range@13`.

Comment: @ruebenko, good point, I added that as a note. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
ExampleArray = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, \
{11}, {12}, {13}};

k = 3;
res = Join @@@ Partition[ExampleArray, k, k, 1, {}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13}} *)
```

Going back:

```
Join @@ (Partition[#, 1] & /@ res)
(*{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Two variations of using `Partition` have been presented.  Let me compare their performance, and offer a third method.

For simplicity I shall assume that the input is a packed array.  This can have a major impact on the ranking of methods as a described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22427/121).

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing @ Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

a = {Range@500000}\[Transpose]; (*sample data, packed *)
k = 4;

Partition[Flatten @ a, k, k, 1, {}] // timeAvg  (* Pinguin Dirk *)
Join @@@ Partition[a, k, k, 1, {}]  // timeAvg  (* ruebenko *)
```

> 0.02496
>
> 0.1842

Flattening before partitioning is faster on this data.

From past experience I know that using non-default padding e.g. `{}` will slow `Partition` considerably when using packed arrays.  Therefore we can speed this process by separating that operation.

```
merge[a_, k_Integer] := 
  Module[{b = Partition[Flatten @ a, k, k, 1]},
    b[[-1]] = b[[-1]] ~Drop~ Mod[Length @ a, k, 1 - k];
    b
  ]

merge[a, k] // timeAvg
```

> 0.003368

On the packed data this is ~ 7.4X faster.  However, on unpackable data it is of no benefit, and in fact slightly slower:

```
a = List /@ RandomChoice["a" ~CharacterRange~ "z", 500000];
k = 7;

Partition[Flatten@a, k, k, 1, {}] // timeAvg

merge[a, k]                       // timeAvg
```

> 0.03056
>
> 0.03556