# Avoiding zeros in ArrayReshape

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the list `list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` and imagine I wanted to change it to `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8}}`. How can I do this?

Using `ArrayReshape` in the usual manner

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
ArrayReshape[list, {3, 3}]
```

yields `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 0}}`. Is it possible to use `ArrayReshape` and avoid that extra 0 at the end? Essentially, I want to reshape my list according to its size.

Comment: I would have expected `ArrayReshape[list, {3, 3}, Nothing]` to work, but it does not.

Comment: You probably need `Activate[ArrayReshape[list, {3, 3}, Inactive@Nothing]]`

Comment: One could also use `ResourceFunction["NearEqualPartition"]` to ask for 3 sublists with roughly equal size.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
Partition[list, UpTo[3]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}}

Answer (score 9):

It seems that using `ArrayReshape` and modifying, if needed, the last entry to remove trailing zeros is faster than using `Partition` or using `Inactive @ Nothing` padding:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4]
f1 = Partition[#, UpTo[#2]] &; (* from Okkes's answer *)
f2 = Partition[#, #2, #2, 1, {}] &;
f3 = Activate @ ArrayReshape[#, 
  {Ceiling[Length[#]/#2], #2}, Inactive @ Nothing] &; (* from MarcoB's answer *)
f4 = Module[{p = ArrayReshape[#, {Floor[Length[#]/#2], #2}], m = Mod[Length@#, #2]},
      If[m == 0, p, Join @@ {p, {#[[-m ;;]]}}]] &;
```

***Timings:***

```
n = 999999;
k = 199;
list = Range[n];

First[RepeatedTiming[r1 = f1[list, k]]]
```

> 0.078

```
First[RepeatedTiming[r2 = f2[list, k]]]
```

> 0.075

```
First[RepeatedTiming[r3 = f3[list, k]]]
```

> 0.094

```
First[RepeatedTiming[r4 = f4[list, k]]]
```

> 0.012

```
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

> True

When `n` is divisible by `k` (so that `ArrayReshape` produces a rectangular array with no paddings):

```
k = 99;

First[RepeatedTiming[r1 = f1[list, k]]]
```

> 0.083

```
First[RepeatedTiming[r2 = f2[list, k]]]
```

> 0.075

```
First[RepeatedTiming[r3 = f3[list, k]]]
```

> 0.0072

```
First[RepeatedTiming[r4 = f4[list, k]]]
```

> 0.0071

```
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

> True

Answer (score 8):

Using `Partition` with `UpTo` is clearly the most expedient answer here, as shown above. However, this got me wondering how one could force `ArrayReshape` into service anyway, just for fun. For instance, we could twist the use of the padding parameter in `ArrayReshape` to force it to pad with `Nothing` (or the [vanishing function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/27951) `##&[]`), as in either of the following, which is then removed when evaluated:

```
ArrayReshape[Range[8], {3, 3}, Hold@Nothing] // ReleaseHold
ArrayReshape[Range[8], {3, 3}, Inactive@Nothing] // Activate
```

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}}`

---

After posting the answer, I refreshed the page to see that this was [brought up in comments as well](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212466/avoiding-zeros-in-arrayreshape/212476#comment544159_212466).

Answer (score 7):

[`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html) is implemented using `` Internal`Deflatten `` (at least in version 10.1).  This function requires $n \times m$ elements, or at least behaves strangely when this is not provided.  I am guessing this relates to  memory pointers in the low-level implementation.

```
Internal`Deflatten[Range@8, {3, 3}]
Internal`Deflatten[Range@8, {3, 3}]
Internal`Deflatten[Range@8, {3, 3}]
Internal`Deflatten[Range@8, {3, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 281500746514433}}
>
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 300647710721}}
>
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 411062144}}
>
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 7164775599194924370}}
> ```

*Note:* If we unpack the list it doesn't work at all:

```
list = List @@ Range@8;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list]
Internal`Deflatten[list, {3, 3}]
```

> ```
> False
>
> Internal`Deflatten[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 3}]
> ```

This is ultimately why something like this also fails:

```
 ArrayReshape[Range@8, {3, 3}, Unevaluated @ Unevaluated[## &[]] ]  (* does not work *)
```

To avoid this any input to `ArrayReshape` is first padded with [`ArrayPad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html) or trimmed to $length = n \times m$.

[`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) drops in speed when using `{}` padding, at least in some cases, probably due to working around a similar low-level implementation.  I used a method similar to kglr's but for `Partition` here:

- [Reversibly merging sets of $k$ adjacent elements in an array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28416/121#28428)
- [Partition array without unpacking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128133/121)

Closely related:

- [UnFlatten an array into a ragged matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58215/121)

---

### Silly games

Just having fun using the above knowledge to break `ArrayReshape`:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo /: {x__Integer, foo[] ..} := Developer`ToPackedArray[{x}]

ArrayReshape[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 3}, foo[]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 470483008}, {36571776, 8, 5100273664}}
> ```