# Partition array without unpacking

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

What is the simplest way to partition a list into equal-length sublists, allow the last sublist to be shorter of necessary, and avoid unpacking?

[`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) doesn't usually unpack:

```
arr = RandomReal[1, 100000];

Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr]
(* True *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Partition[arr, 25000]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

But it does if we allow the last sublist to be shorter:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Partition[arr, UpTo@30000]
(* {False, False, False, False} *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Partition[arr, 30000, 30000, {1, 1}, {}]
(* {False, False, False, False} *)
```

**Question 1:**  Why isn't the result packed?  Is there any reason I didn't think of or is this case just not optimized?

**Question 2:** What's an elegant way to avoid this problem?

Comment: It's nice to see this old issue getting some attention.  My work-around is pretty much the same as yours: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28428/121

Comment: Related: [(58215)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58215/121)

Answer (score 8):

One could use `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` to get packed subarrays.

*Code.*

```
partition[l_List, n_Integer] := With[{qr = QuotientRemainder[Length[l], n]},

   If[qr[[2]] == 0,
      Partition[l, n],
      Internal`PartitionRagged[l, Append[ConstantArray[n, qr[[1]]], qr[[2]]]]
   ]

];
```

*Usage.*

```
list = Range[100];

p1 = partition[list, 25];
Length /@ p1
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ p1
(* {25, 25, 25, 25} *)
(* {True, True, True, True} *)

p2 = partition[list, 30];
Length /@ p2
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ p2
(* {30, 30, 30, 10} *)
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Alternatively, ``Internal`PartitionRagged[l, Append[ConstantArray[n, qr[[1]]], qr[[2]] /. 0 -> Nothing]]``, tho the outer list is not packed.

Comment: Yes, ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` does not bother trying to pack the outer list for partitions of the same size. I used `Partition` for this situation to meet OP's requirements.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the answer for Question 1 is that Partition doesn't only return packed subarrays, it returns a complete packed array.

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ @ Partition[arr, 25000]
(* True *)
```

When it can't keep everything packed, it gives up and fully unpacks everything.  This of course doesn't mean that it couldn't in principle behave in a smarter way.

The best solutions I found to Question 2 are unfortunately still not very simple, so suggestions are welcome.  I didn't find the solution to be trivial, so I thought it is worth sharing:

```
Clear[part]
part[arr_, n_] /; Divisible[Length[arr], n] := Partition[arr, n]
part[arr_, n_] :=
 Join[
  Partition[arr, n, n, {1, -1}],
  {Take[arr, -Mod[Length[arr], n]]}
 ]
```

This seems simple, but you may simplify this further to use `Append[a, b]` instead of `Append[a, {el}]`.  It turns out that `Append` is another one of those unpack-eager functions, so using `Join` was critical.  If we want `Append`, we must unpack to level 1 only manually:

```
part[arr_, n_] :=
 Append[
  Developer`FromPackedArray[Partition[arr, n, n, {1, -1}], 1],
  Take[arr, -Mod[Length[arr], n]]
 ]
```

Comment: `part[Range[12], 4]` seems to return a dangling empty list for me, and ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[part[Range[12], 4]]`` thus returns `False`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  I'm not in a good shape today.

Comment: For what it's worth you can unpack one level using merely `List @@`.

Comment: Your second function is still leaving dangling lists: `part[{1, 2, 3}, 3]` -> `{{1, 2, 3}, {}}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It still needs the Divisible test.

Comment: And despite the comments above *I* still forgot to unpack to level one...

Answer (score 6):

I hesitated to post this as it is essentially a re-post of my answer to [Reversibly merging sets of $k$ adjacent elements in an array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/reversibly-merging-sets-of-k-adjacent-elements-in-an-array/28428#28428) but it occurs to me that this is a better place for that answer anyway.

My work-around was similar to your own except that instead of using `Join` I used a different padding specification and then trimmed the trailing list with a `Part` assignment.  Improving(?) that to use `MapAt` instead (in operator form) gives a fairly clean function:

```
fn[a_, k_Integer] :=
  List @@ Partition[a, k, k, 1] //
    MapAt[# ~Drop~ Mod[Length @ a , k, 1 - k] &, -1]
```

Test:

```
Table[fn[Range@i, 3], {i, 9}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{1}},
>  {{1, 2}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {4}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}},
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
> }
> ```