# Why does MapAt unpack individual elements?

Tags: core-language, map, language-design, packed-arrays

(In case this is version specific I am using *Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows.)

While responding to [Partition array without unpacking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128133/121) I noticed something about [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) that I don't believe I have before:

```
pQ = Developer`PackedArrayQ;
x = Range @ Range @ 3
pQ[x]
Map[pQ, x]
MapAt[pQ, x, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
>
> False
>
> {True, True, True}
>
> {{1}, False, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

Note the last output line: the second element is `False` rather than `True`.  The element `{1, 2}` has apparently been unpacked by `MapAt` before the function that is mapped ever sees it.  Also notably the other elements are not unpacked:

```
pQ /@ MapAt[pQ, x, 2]   (*  {True, False, True}  *)
```

It is understandable that it would unpack a list which it was going to operate *within* , e.g. `MapAt[f, x, {2, 1}]` but not a list passed verbatim to the operating function.  I cannot think of a good reason for `MapAt` to unpack in this case, and without a counterargument I would consider it a bug.

Is this a bug or oversight, or is there a reason for this behavior that I am failing to consider?

Comment: v11 does the same.  I considered asking this same question earlier today, but then I didn't.

Comment: v.10.0.1 on Mac OS 10.10.5 does the same.

Comment: My guess is that `MapAt` takes complex position specification, even `Span` is allowed.  It would take relatively complex logic to figure out what to unpack and what to leave packed, so they didn't implement that.  At least this is why I didn't write about MapAt when I complained about Partition and Append to support.  It seems there's still plenty of opportunity for optimization.

Comment: Same result in v9.0.1 and v8.0.4

Comment: @Szabolcs I am not sure I agree with that reasoning.  If `MapAt` started by unpacking *everything* would have figured it was a design decision along those lines, but since it manages to keep elements one and three in this example packed it is obviously possible to unpack only some elements and not others.  I do not see the need/reason for unpacking the deepest level.  I don't see how `Span` factors into this.  If we use `MapAt[pQ, x, 2 ;; 3]` (which also unpacks) it is apparent that neither two nor three *need* to be unpacked.  (continued)

Comment: I mean that if `x` is a packed array, then it unpacks all levels, not just up to the first level.  In your example `x` is a list of packed arrays, but `x` itself isn't packed (its ragged)

Comment: If we used `MapAt[pQ, x, {3, 2 ;; 3}]` it is apparent that `{1,2,3}` can/should be unpacked, but why unpack any elements deeper than that?  For example if we start with `x[[3, 1]] = Range[4, 6];` why should `{4, 5, 6}` be unpacked in that example?